# Unwanted commas getting inserted in a CSV file after an edit in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a csv file to work with in a visual studio.

Example file data..

```
Address,included
City,State,Country,Zip
Boston,MA,US,02120

Customer,included
Name,Id
a,1
```

Now if I open this file in Excel to change the zip value my newly saved file would be..

```
Address,included,,
City,State,Country,Zip
Boston,MA,US,02119
,,,
Customer,included,,
Name,Id,,
a,1,,
```

Meaning to say It converts the file to have each lines' columns count equal to a line with maximum number of columns.
Which is 4 in this case. For a line (City,State,Country,Zip)

My question is how do I avoid this unwanted insertion of commas (,).
I am saving the changes by replacing the file with a same file name. (in CSV (comma delimited) format)

Before saving it warns me that

```
"Test.csv may contain features that are not compatible with CSV (Comma delimited.)"
```

How do I avoid this unwanted insertion of commas? Is there any other format in which I should be saving my file after edit?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do this in excel.

Open the file in Notepad, or Notepad++ or any other text editor. Edit it in that, then save it.

Comment: I can do that in Visual Studio itself. But being able to edit in Excel would make it easier as the number of columns get bigger and complicated.